# How to return single integer value from Volley in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to get a single integer value with Volley.

> In this example the number is 14

**In the debugger** I get the correct value ***14*** and assign it to vNumber while in the try/catch block but then when I try to return the vNumber I get value ***0*** as returned number.

This is the JSON result.

`{"result":[{"version":"14"}]}`

Here is the code for this function:

> ```
> int vNumber;
>
> public int getVersionNumber() {
>
>     StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GET_VERSION_NUMBER,
>             new Response.Listener<String>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onResponse(String response) {
>                     try {
>                         JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
>                         JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("result");
>                         JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
>
>                         vNumber = jsonObject.getInt("version");
>
>                     } catch (JSONException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                         Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e);
>                     }
>                 }
>             },
>             new Response.ErrorListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>                     Log.d(TAG, "VolleyError: " + error);
>                 }
>             });
>
>     RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
>     requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
>
>     return vNumber;
> }
> ```

I already tried using sharedPreferences and putting the value inside a textView (the value is correct when I set it in a textView) and then getting it from it but it's still not working. I could create a new table inside my local DB and save the data but it is not necessary in this use case.

Do you have any suggestions on how the return the correct value, and what am I doing wrong here?

Cheers

Comment: Fetch Data from the cloud is an Async call.  So what is happening when it is making API call, return vNumber will give 0( default Int value).

Once you get value after api call then consume it.

Comment: @KishanMaurya Hi, in the try/catch I get the correct value and I can use it in a Toast, place it in a textView or assign it to another variable, but as soon as I leave the try/catch block I get 0, even if I use the new vars or getText() method. The only thing I can think of rn is to save it to a DB when I get it from the call, but I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: This is the correct behavior of code. Can you give context to what you are doing with vNumber after returing??

when code flow reach in try catch block, you will have the correct value. So you have to use it from here only.  either toast, textview or store anywhere.

I think you are calling this getVersionNumber() and it will give you 0 because of async nature of volley api call.

Comment: @KishanMaurya I am comparing it with the number that is stored in shared preferences, on app open, and if the numbers are the same there is no further action but if the local number is lower than the fetched number I fetch some additional data. What do you suggest I do to return the correct value? Because like you said, at this moment I can only use it while in try catch.

Comment: Yes, do your comparion after you get value from api call. 
i.e after this line vNumber = jsonObject.getInt("version");
// add some method for your operation..

Either make a synchronous API call ( which is not recommended )  or do any operation after you get value from api call.

Comment: @KishanMaurya oh yeah, that's one way to go about it. It didn't cross my mind to do any functionalities inside try-catch. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void fetchVersionNumber() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GET_VERSION_NUMBER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("result");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                        vNumber = jsonObject.getInt("version");
                        compareAndUpdate(vNumber)

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "VolleyError: " + error);
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void compareAndUpdate(int vNumber){

//compare and do your operation
// Get from sharedPref and compare
}
```